# JS - How to submit form onclick and send submit button

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button, submit

I need to submit form by button which is out of scope of the form by JavaSript.

```
<form>
  <input name="data" type="text">
  <input type="submit" name="send" id="send-button" style="display: none">
</form>

<button onclick="$('#send-button').click() || .submit()"></button>
```

The button **#send-button** is visible and I need to send whole form to server. It means I receive **$data** and **$send** (both).

Now I am getting just the **$data**.

Any idea?

Comment: what exactly expect to receive in server ?  I can't imagine sending a button because it has not information.

Answer (score 6):

You can do with javascript form method

```
<button onclick="document.forms[0].submit()"></button>
```

if you have multiple forms in the document then set id to the form

```
<form id="form1">
  <input name="data" type="text">
  <input type="submit" name="send" id="send-button" style="display: none">
</form>
<button onclick="document.getElementById("form1").submit()"></button>
```

Comment: He is saying that he wants to receive the button in server, he already now how send the form using onclick event

Comment: Oh, sorry. Now I tried to run it on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/97xtk76m/) and it works how I assumed. The problem is somewhere in my other JS libraries probably :-( When you look at request data, there are data input and submitted button name...

Answer (score 4):

Give the form a name:

```
    <form name="myform">
        <a href="javascript: submitform()">Submit</a>
    </form>
```

Submit form function:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function submitform()
        {
           document.myform.submit();
        }
    </script>
```

Invoke submission:

```
    document.forms["myform"].submit();
```

Answer (score -2):

you should add value attribute on submit button like that

```
<input type="submit" name="send" value="xyz" id="send-button" style="display: none">
```

i think you will received both values