# Value save in Database is 0 codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can someone please help me to fix my problem here, the codes given below is under MODEL.

My problem is that the value inserted in database is 0 (literally zero) the exact value not shown on the table.

MODEL:

```
$prcode=$this->input->post('prcode');
$supplier=$this->input->post('supplier');
$data = array('prcode'=>$prcode,'supplier'=>$supplier);
$this->db->insert('t_approved',$data);
```

CONTROLLER:

```
$this->ARequestModel->create($data);
```

VIEW:

```
<form method = "post">
    <input type="submit"  class="btn green button-submit" onClick = "windows.location <?php echo site_url("ARequest/create");?>" value="Approved">
</form>
```

Comment: which type of value are you trying to insert@Jhesie

Comment: <label class="control-label col-md-3">Supplier <span class="required"> * </span></label>
<div class="col-md-4">              <select class="form-control select2me" required="required" name="sup" id="sup" onChange="loadtableMaterialsBySupplier(value)">               <option value="">Select...</option>              <?php                        foreach($getSupplier as $row)
            { 
              echo '<option value="'.$row->supplier_id.'">'.$row->company_name.'</option>';
         }?>
</select> 
</div>
</div>

---> from this

Comment: try to follow mvc pattern for inserting a data https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html

Comment: are you trying to insert integer or varchar or text ?

Comment: where is your form? show your data base stracture

Comment: this is my database:

prcode->varchar
supplier->varchar

i'm trying to input a character 

but in my database it appear 0

Comment: Please edit your question to add more information, instead of putting it inside comments. You might also look at the formatting options to improve readbility.

Comment: thanks for your advice

Comment: this is my database: 
`prcode->varchar` 
`supplier->varchar`

 i'm trying to input a character but in my database it appear 0

Answer (score 0):

Use Code like this

Controller:

```
function create(){
        $prcode=$this->input->post('prcode');
        $supplier=$this->input->post('sup');
        $data = array(
        'prcode'=>$prcode,
        'supplier'=>$supplier
        );
$this->ARequestModel->create($data);
}
```

Model:

```
function create($data){
$this->db->insert('t_approved',$data);
}
```

Comment: this is my error after i try your suggestion **Undefined variable: data**

Comment: please provide your view full code from where you are submitting data

Comment: **view 1**
`<form id="submit_form"  method="post">
**input value**
<label>ID <span class="required">
* </span></label>
<div class="col-md-4"><input type ="text" name="id" id="id"/></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
             <label>Purchase Request # <span class="required"> * </span></label>
<div class="col-md-4">`

Comment: **view 2**
              `<select class="form-control select2me" required="required" name="pr" id="pr" onChange="loadtableMaterials(value)">              <option value="">Select...</option>               <?php if($getpureq > 0) {                            foreach ($getpureq as $row)  {                            echo '<option value='.$row['id'].' title='.$row['des'].'>'.$row['name'].'</option>';                 }  }                            ?>             </select>
<input type="text"  name="prcode" id="prcode" disabled/>              </div>
</div>`

Comment: **view 3**
`<div class="form-group">
<label>Supplier <span class="required"> * </span></label>
<div class="col-md-4">
<select class="form-control select2me" required="required" name="sup" id="sup" onChange="loadtableMaterialsBySupplier(value)">
<option value="">Select...</option>
<?php foreach($getSupplier as $row {  echo '<option value="'.$row->supplier_id.'">'.$row->company_name.'</option>';
  }?> </select>              </div></div><div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
<h3 class="block">Confirm purchase order materials</h3>              </div>               
</div>`

Comment: **view 4**

**buttons**          
`<div class="form-actions">
<div id="actionButtons">
<input type="submit"  class="btn green button-submit" onClick = "windows.location <?php echo site_url("ARequest/create");?>" value="Approved">`

Comment: sorry, I try to post on comment the whole code in view but it cannot be... so I try to batch by batch, hope you understand it and please help me to my problem @Gopal Bhuva

Comment: see my updated answer and also make this field readonly in your view `<input type="text" name="prcode" id="prcode" readonly/>`

Comment: still the value of my database is 0 @gopal bhuva

Comment: `prcode
0`

this is the output in my database, only zero the value that I have chosen does not shown in my database
@Gopal Bhuva

Comment: change button `onclick="document.getElementById("submit_form").submit()"`

Comment: sorry to ask... is this **submit()**.. pertaining to button or function sorry @Gopal Bhuva

Comment: it will submit your form with data for more [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737894/js-how-to-submit-form-onclick-and-send-submit-button)

Comment: and also try to change your column data type varchar in database

Comment: it is already VARCHAR data type... by the way I use bootstrap in this template @Gopal Bhuva